# Entity Framework 4.1 Many to Many Self Referencing Relationship Payload issue

Tags: entity-framework

I've been spending hours and hours trying to figure out the answer to this, reviewing other posts but nothing is helping me with this issues.

The goal is i want to track the relationship of people in our organization with other people in the organization.

I have two tables

1. `Persons`
2. `Person_Person` with an ID for the first and second person and an extra column called relationship type.

I want to have a navigation property on persons to access all the relationships with other people.

For some reason when i try to do

```
newperson.Relationships.add(new Person_Person(){Person1= person});
```

i get an extra row.

Something is not adding up please help me sort this out

Update#1

Ok let me clarify i have class called person

```
public class Person {
               int personID;
               string Name;
              public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships;
```

}

```
public class Relationship {

      int RelationshipID {get; set;}
      public virtual Person person1{get; set;}
      public virtual Person person2{get; set;}
      public string relationshipType {get; set;}
```

}

I want to be able to do two things, one is to be able to add a relationshp through the relationships collection by doing

```
Person newperson = new Person();
newperson.Relationships.add(person2);
```

This results in an extra row.

The other is if I add the person through the relationship table such as

```
Relationship relationship= new Relationship();
relationship.person1= person1;
relationship.person2= person2;
relationship.relationshiptype="father";
db.Relationships.add(relationship);
```

This works but i want it to appear in the relationships called in the specific person

How do i do this i hope i was able to clarify i know the code isn't perfect syntax wise i wrote it on the fly. but please help me with the logic.

Comment: Where is the extra row? Could you provide us with more detail about said row?

Comment: What is the other end of the relationship that `Relationships` property participate? When you add a new instance to a collection it will result in a new row.

Comment: Writing questions "on the fly" is not good. Your question is a total chaos. How can you add some unknown class called `Person_Person` to a collection which holds objects of type `Relationship`? How can you add a `person2` (which is either a `Person` or, if not, has a weird name, who knows) to a Relationships collection? What is "an extra row"? You still didn't clarify this. If you want a useful answer please put some effort into your question and don't let the people *guess* what problem you have. For now I'm voting to close the question because it's difficult to say what's being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm not getting what you're trying to do, but it seems that you are overcomplicating a bit.

Create a Relationship class, like this:

```
public class Relationship
{
  public int RelationshipID { get; set; }

  // Link the two people together.
  public virtual Person Person1 { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person2 { get; set; }
  // You could also add a RelationshipType or something along those lines if you choose.
}
```

The Person class would look like this:

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // Add whatever else you want.
}
```

Then create your DbContext class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
}
```

In your repository, you create a new relationship like this:

```
public class MyRepository
{
  MyContext db = new MyContext();

  public void AddRelationship(Person person1, Person person2) 
  {
    var relationship = new Relationship
    {
      Person1 = person1,
      Person2 = person2
    }

    db.Relationships.Add(relationship);
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

All you have to do is call AddRelationship from whatever class (your controller, or whatever) that needs it.

Comment: Let's say i want to have a collection called relationships on class person how would i go about doing this

Comment: There are 2 issues: 1) Your `AddRelationship` method will create two new persons and not only the relationship. You must either attach `person1` and `person2` to the context `db` you are using to create the relationship or - if `person1` and `person2` are already attached to another context - use the same context and not create a new one. 2) `Person.Relationships` will lead to trouble because `Relationship` has *two* navigation properties refering to `Person`. EF won't detect the correct inverse property and will create *three* associations which likely doesn't represent the correct model.

Comment: @Slauma - Good call. (Like I said, it was 7AM when I responded to the question.) I'm going to remove it. Quite honestly, I don't understand what he's trying to accomplish by having "Relationships" as PART of Person. (Maybe DevTeam can respond.)

Comment: I need to track how people in the system are related. when i load a person i want to be able to see all his relationships with other people and load it into a datagrid(WPF). I did was slauma said and it worked but it doesn;t regonize inverse, unless i add it the other way into the database by reversing the order.